# How did a hacker produce this GET request?

Tags: django, apache, web-services, ubuntu

I am just about to go live with a website and am addressing security issues. The site has been public for some time but not linked to the search engines.

I log all incoming requests and today noticed this one:

```
GET /home/XXXXX/code/repositories/YYYYY-website/templates
```

where XXXXX is a sudo user on my server and YYYYY is my company name.
This is actually the structure of my Django project code.
My website is coded using Django and runs under Apache2 on Ubuntu.
My question is how can this guy possibly know the underlying code/directory structure on my server, in order to create this request?

Their IP is : 66.249.65.221.
They come up as 100% a hacker on https://ip-46.com

Any contributions welcome.

**EDIT1 25/11/2019**

With some helpful input from [Loïc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3322400/lo%C3%AFc), I have done some investigation.

The Ubuntu 18.04 server is locked down as far as logging in goes - you can only get in with one of my private keys. The PostgreSQL is locked down - it will only accept connections from one IP where my dev machines reside. RabbitMQ is locked down - it won't accept ANY external incoming connections. The robots.txt allows all crawling but the robots meta restricts access to about 12 pages only.

Somebody who knows Django, would know how to form this directory path if they knew the Django project directory but they also have this relative to root on the server. The only place where this is available is in the Apache2 config file. Obviously Apache needs to know where to pick up the Django web server.

I am 99% sure that this 'hacker' got this via some sort of command to Apache. Everything is redirected to port 443 https. The above GET request doesn't actually do anything because the url doesn't exist.

So to make the question more refined. How can a hacker pull my Django absolute project path from my Apache2 config file?

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of different ways to learn about the directory structure of a given server.

The easiest usually being error logs;
If in your django settings, `DEBUG` is set to `True`, it is very easy for an attacker to get the directory structure of your project.

Then there is LFI, a security issue allowing an attacker to read local files. It's then possible to read some logs, or apache configuration to learn what is your project directory...

The problem could come from another service running on your server as well...

One cannot really give you a complete answer on this topic, as there are a lot of different ways this could happen.

Comment: My site has DEBUG = False. Services are Apache2, PostgreSQL, RabbitMQ. Your comment is very general. Given these services, specifically, what is one of "a lot of different ways"?

Comment: Yes my comment is very general, it couldn't be precise because we obviously lack a lot of information.
Maybe you run an old version of ubuntu which uses vulnerables services.
Maybe your PostgreSQL server is opened to the internet, and credentials are weak.
Maybe your python code is vulnerable to RCE or LFI.
Maybe the hacker knew about the project structure because he contributed or you posted the info somewhere as you just did here.
Maybe your computer is infected.
Maybe some logs are accessible from outside.
Maybe you use a vulnerable/backdoored python library.
...

Comment: Or maybe you gave google too much information.
By googling the IP I get this : https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/66.249.65.221
"Googlebot"

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. I have 20 years as a C++/Python/C# developer but only 6 months creating a webserver. Ubuntu 18.04 fully up-to-date. PostgreSQL is locked down, only accesible from ine IP

Comment: PostgreSQL is locked down, only accessible from one IP where my dev machines are. Python vunerable to RCE or LFI - I don't know. I haven't posted the structure publicly. The RabbitMQ stuff is locked down. All server logins are by private key only. If he knows Django, he can guess the template directory, but he needs the root folder of the Django project. The only place this is stated is in an Apache config file.

Comment: So my guess is that somehow he has got the root Django project directory via Apache2 on port 80 or 443 - do you know how he could do this in principle?

Comment: I don't, but the fact that a bot got your full directory is strange.
I'd bet on robots.txt

Comment: I've done some more investigation. Am going to an an edit to the question. Thanks again for your pointers with this Loic.